# WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <. of sequential type is unconnected in block <>

Tags: vhdl

I have a problem that is "WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <DataInputCRC.PROC_CRCOneData> of sequential type is unconnected in block <SPI_Slave>." inside the "DataInputCRC" process. I don't understand why is that, how to remove this warning. Below is my entire code.

```
--CPOL = 0, CPHA = 0, MSB transmit
--không được ghi data vào khi chưa bật device
--bật device bằng cách nss= '0'
--sự kiện SCK xay ra sau khi nss = '0', sự kiện NSS xay ra sau khi sự kiện SCK
--ghi sự kiện CRC ngay sau khi ghi data cuối cùng vào SPI, trước khi data được dịch chuyển sang ARC_DataMiso, đối với truyền một data thì phải ghi sự kiện CRCEvent đồng thời với ghi data vào spi
--phải ghi data mới vào spi trước khi DATAMISO truyền xong
--không được ghi data mới vào spi sau khi ghi sự kiện CRC, phải đợi đến khi data empty trống mới được ghi vào
--sau khi truyền xong crc phải ghi nss = 1
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity SPI_Slave is
    generic(ENT_Leangth: integer:= 8;
            ENT_CRCEnable: boolean:= true;--bật CRC Check
            ENT_Polynomial: std_logic_vector(8 downto 0):= "100000101"
            );
    port(ENT_ClkIn: in std_logic:= '0';
        ENT_DataNewEvent: in std_logic:= '0';
        ENT_DataIn: in std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');
        ENT_DataOut: out std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');
        ENT_SCK: in std_logic:= '0';
        ENT_MOSI: in std_logic:= '0';
        ENT_MISO: out std_logic:= '0';
        ENT_NSS: in std_logic:= '1';
        ENT_DataEmpty: out std_logic:= '1';
        ENT_DataReceiveEvent: out std_logic:= '0';--sự kiện khi nhận xong một data
        ENT_DeviceResetEvent: std_logic:= '0';
        ENT_CRCEvent: std_logic:= '0';--kích hoặt CRC
        ENT_Error: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):= (others=> '0')--lỗi
        );
end entity SPI_Slave;
architecture SPI_Slave_Behavioral of SPI_Slave is
    --DeviceStatus
    signal ARC_DeviceStatus: boolean:= false;-- SPI chưa hoạt động
    --DataMisoTemp
    signal ARC_DataMisoTemp: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1)downto 0):= (others=> '0');--data tạm 
    signal ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag: std_logic:= '1';--cờ data trống
    signal ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset cờ 
    signal ARC_DataMisoTempError: std_logic:= '0';--lỗi khi data tạm thời chưa được ghi vào DataMiso lại ghi data mới vào
    --DataMiso
    signal ARC_DataMiso: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');
    signal ARC_DataMisoReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset cờ
    signal ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag: std_logic:= '1';-- cờ data Miso trống
    --DataMosi
    signal ARC_DataMosi: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others => '0');
    --signal ARC_DataMosiEmptyFlag: std_logic:= '1';--chưa có data trong dataMosi
    signal ARC_DataMosiEmptySet: std_logic:= '0';----set tín hiệu ARC_DataMosiEmptyFlag
    signal ARC_DataMosiEmptyReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset tín hiệu ARC_DataMosiEmptyFlag
    --signal ARC_DataTransmitEnd: boolean:= false;--tín hiệu cho thay chưa bắt đầu truyền data cuối(không phải truyền data crc)
    signal ARC_DataReceiveEvent: std_logic:= '0';--sự kiện khi nhận xong một frame data
    --DataMosiTemp
    signal ARC_DataMosiTemp: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');-- data mosi tạm thời, chờ đọc
    --Counter
    signal ARC_Counter: integer range (ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0:= (ENT_Leangth -1);
    signal ARC_CounterSCKEvent: std_logic:= '0';--sự kiện bộ đếm
    signal ARC_CounterSCKEventReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset tín hiệu ARC_CounterSCKEvent
    signal ARC_DataFrameComputer: boolean:= false;-- chưa truyền xong một khung data
    --NSS
    signal ARC_NSSErrorHighNSS: std_logic:= '0';--lỗi nss tăng lênh mức '1'
    signal ARC_NSSErrorLowNSS: std_logic:= '0';--lỗi nss xuốn mức '0'
    --CRC Miso
    constant ARC_CRCZeroVector: std_logic_vector(((ENT_Leangth *2) -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');
    constant ARC_CRCPolynomial: std_logic_vector(((ENT_Leangth *2) -1) downto 0):= ENT_Polynomial&((ENT_Leangth *2) -1 - ENT_Polynomial'length downto 0=> '0');
    alias ARC_CRCCLK is ENT_ClkIn;
    alias ARC_CRCDataNewEvent is ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag;
    signal ARC_CRCCheckError: std_logic:= '0';--không có lỗi khi kiểm tra crc
    signal ARC_CRCDataNewEventReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset 
    signal ARC_CRCDataNewEventFlag: std_logic:= '0';--cờ cho biết có data mới trong DataMiso
    signal ARC_CRCDataInput: std_logic_vector(((ENT_Leangth *2)-1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');
    signal ARC_CRCDataInputCompute: std_logic:= '0';-- đã hết data, tiếng hành hoàng thành crc
    signal ARC_CRCEvent: std_logic:= '0';--sự kiện khi ENT_CRCEvent tăng lênh '1'
    signal ARC_CRCEventReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset ARC_CRCEvent
    signal ARC_CRCDataOutput: std_logic_vector(ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0):= (others=> '0');--data CRC
    signal ARC_CRCDataOne: boolean:= true;--chỉ truyền 1 data
    --signal ARC_CRCTransmitComputer: boolean:= false;--chưa truyền xong crc
    --signal ARC_CRCTransmitComputerReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset
    --signal ARC_CRCTransmitStart: boolean:= false;-- bắt đầu truyền crc
    --signal ARC_CRCTransmitStartReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset tín hiệu ARC_CRCTransmitStart;
    signal ARC_CRCStart: boolean:= false;-- chưa bắt đầu truyền crc
    signal ARC_CRCStartReset: std_logic:= '0';-- Reset
    --CRC MOSI
    alias ARC_CRCDataMosiInputNewEvent is ARC_DataReceiveEvent;--sự kiện khi có data mới
    alias ARC_CRCDataMosiReceiveComputer is ARC_CRCStart;-- chưa nhận hết data
    alias ARC_CRCDataMosiCheckEvent is ARC_DataMosiEmptySet;--sự kiện kiểm tra crc nhận từ server 
    signal ARC_CRCDataMosiCheckAccess: boolean:= false;-- không cho phép kiểm tra crc
    signal ARC_CRCDataMosiTemp: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth *2) -1 downto 0):= (others=> '0');
    signal ARC_CRCDataMosiOne: std_logic:= '1';--chỉ nhận 1 data
    signal ARC_CRCDataMosiComputer: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');--data crc khi tính toáng xong
    --signal ARC_CRCDataMosiReceive: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');--crc nhận từ server
    signal ARC_CRCDataMosiComputerEvent: std_logic:= '0';-- sự kiện sau khi tính toán xong crc
    --signal ARC_CRCDataMosiComputerEventReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset
    signal ARC_CRCDataMosiOK: boolean:= false;-- chưa hoàng thành crc
begin   
    --set DataMiSO
    --ENT_cc<= ARC_CRCDataInput;
    ENT_MISO<= ARC_DataMiso(ARC_Counter);
    ENT_DataOut<= ARC_DataMosiTemp;
    ENT_DataEmpty<= ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag;
    ENT_DataReceiveEvent<= ARC_DataReceiveEvent;
    ENT_Error<= (ARC_NSSErrorHighNSS or ARC_NSSErrorLowNSS) & ARC_DataMisoTempError & ARC_CRCCheckError;
    DataMisoControlInput:process(ENT_DataNewEvent, ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyReset, ENT_DeviceResetEvent)is
        variable PROC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag: std_logic:= '1';--cờ data temp trống
        variable PROC_DataMisoTempError: std_logic:= '0';--không có lỗi
    begin
        if(ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1' or ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyReset = '1')then
            --device reset
            PROC_DataMisoTempError:= '0';--không có lỗi
            ARC_DataMisoTempError<= PROC_DataMisoTempError; 
            ARC_DataMisoTemp<= (others=> '0');
            ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag<= '1';
            PROC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag:= '1';
        elsif(ENT_DataNewEvent'event and ENT_DataNewEvent = '1')then
            ARC_DataMisoTemp<= ENT_DataIn;--data mới
            ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag<= '0';
            PROC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag:= ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag;
            if(PROC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag = '0')then--có data, lỗi(data củ trong datamisotemp bị lọi bỏ)
                PROC_DataMisoTempError:= '1';--lỗi, data trong DataMisoTemp chưa được truyền đi
                ARC_DataMisoTempError<= PROC_DataMisoTempError; 
            else
                --data temp không có data
                PROC_DataMisoTempError:= ARC_DataMisoTempError;
                ARC_DataMisoTempError<= PROC_DataMisoTempError; 
            end if;
        end if;
    end process DataMisoControlInput;
    ControlCRC:process(ENT_ClkIn, ARC_CRCStartReset, ARC_DeviceStatus, ENT_DeviceResetEvent, ARC_CRCEvent, ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag, ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag)is
    begin
        if(ARC_CRCStartReset = '1' or ARC_DeviceStatus = false or ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1')then
            ARC_CRCStart<= false;
        elsif(ENT_ClkIn'event and ENT_ClkIn = '1' and ARC_CRCEvent = '1' and ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag = '1' and ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag = '0')then
            ARC_CRCStart<= true;
        end if;
    end process ControlCRC;
    ControlCRCReset: process(ENT_ClkIn, ENT_NSS)is
    begin
        if(ENT_ClkIn'event and ENT_ClkIn = '1')then
            if(ENT_NSS = '1')then
                ARC_CRCStartReset<= '1';
            else
                ARC_CRCStartReset<= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process ControlCRCReset;
    DataMisoControl: process(ENT_ClkIn, Arc_DataMisoReset, ENT_DeviceResetEvent)is
        variable PROC_DataMiso: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');
        variable PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag: std_logic:= '1';--dataMiso trống
        variable PROC_DataTransmitEnd: boolean:= false;-- chưa bắt đầu truyền data cuối cùng(không phải truyền crc)
    begin
        if(ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1' or Arc_DataMisoReset = '1')then
            PROC_DataMiso:= (others=> '0');
            PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag:= '1';--data miso trống
            ARC_DataMiso<= PROC_DataMiso;
            ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag<= PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag;
            ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyReset<= '0';
            ARC_CRCDataInputCompute<= '0';
            PROC_DataTransmitEnd:= false;
            --ARC_DataTransmitEnd<= PROC_DataTransmitEnd;
        elsif(ENT_ClkIn'event and ENT_ClkIn = '1')then
            if(PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag = '1' and ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag = '0' and ENT_CRCEnable = false)then
                -- ghi data mới khi DataMiso đã truyền xong và dataMioTemp có data mới, CRC bị disable, 
                PROC_DataMiso:= ARC_DataMisoTemp;
                ARC_DataMiso<= PROC_DataMiso;
                PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag:= '0';--data miso KHÔNG trống
                ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag<= PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag;
                ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyReset<= '1';--RESERT DATAMISO EMPTY FLAG
                PROC_DataTransmitEnd:= false;
                if(ARC_CRCEvent = '1')then
                    ARC_CRCDataInputCompute<= '1';--đã nhận data miso cuối cùng, bắt đầu hoàng thành crc
                else
                    ARC_CRCDataInputCompute<= '0';
                end if;
            elsif(PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag = '1' and ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyFlag = '0' and ENT_CRCEnable = true and ARC_CRCStart = false and PROC_DataTransmitEnd = false)then
                -- ghi data mới khi DataMiso đã truyền xong và dataMioTemp có data mới, CRC bị disable, 
                PROC_DataMiso:= ARC_DataMisoTemp;
                ARC_DataMiso<= PROC_DataMiso;
                PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag:= '0';--data miso KHÔNG trống
                ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag<= PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag;
                ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyReset<= '1';--RESERT DATAMISO EMPTY FLAG
                if(ARC_CRCEvent = '1')then
                    ARC_CRCDataInputCompute<= '1';--đã nhận data miso cuối cùng, bắt đầu hoàng thành crc
                    PROC_DataTransmitEnd:= true;-- bắt đầu truyền data cuối 
                else
                    ARC_CRCDataInputCompute<= '0';
                    PROC_DataTransmitEnd:= false;
                end if;
            elsif(ENT_CRCEnable = true and ARC_DataFrameComputer = true and ARC_CRCStart = true and PROC_DataTransmitEnd = true)then
                --CRC= enable, và chưa truyền crc, đã truyền xông frame data cuối cùng
                PROC_DataMiso:= ARC_CRCDataOutput;--lấy data crc
                ARC_DataMiso<= PROC_DataMiso;
                PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag:= '0';--data miso KHÔNG trống
                ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag<= PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag;
                ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyReset<= '1';--RESERT DATAMISO EMPTY FLAG
                ARC_CRCDataInputCompute<= '0';
                PROC_DataTransmitEnd:= true;-- bắt đầu truyền data cuối 
            else
                PROC_DataMiso:= ARC_DataMiso;
                ARC_DataMiso<= PROC_DataMiso;
                ARC_DataMisoTempEmptyReset<= '0';
                PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag:= '0';
                PROC_DataMisoEmptyFlag:= ARC_DataMisoEmptyFlag;
                ARC_CRCDataInputCompute<= '0';
            end if;
            --ARC_DataTransmitEnd<= PROC_DataTransmitEnd;
        end if;
    end process DataMisoControl;
    --reset signal ARC_DataMosiEmptyFlag
    ResetDataMisoEmptyFlag: process(ENT_ClkIn, ARC_DeviceStatus)is
    begin
        if(ENT_ClkIn'event and ENT_ClkIn = '1' and ARC_DeviceStatus = true)then
            if(ARC_Counter = (ENT_Leangth -1) and ARC_DataFrameComputer = true)then
                if(ENT_CRCEnable = true and ARC_CRCStart = false)then
                    ARC_DataMisoReset<= '1';--reset datamisoEmptyFlag
                elsif(ENT_CRCEnable = false)then
                    ARC_DataMisoReset<= '1';--reset datamisoEmptyFlag
                else
                    ARC_DataMisoReset<= '0';
                end if;
            else
                ARC_DataMisoReset<= '0';
                --ARC_CRCTransmitComputerReset<= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process ResetDataMisoEmptyFlag;

    --DeviceEnable
    DeviceEnableHighNSS: process(ENT_NSS, ENT_DeviceResetEvent, ARC_DeviceStatus)is
        variable PROC_NSSError: std_logic:= '0';--lỗi nss
    begin
        if(ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1' and ARC_DeviceStatus = false)then
            PROC_NSSError:= '0';
            ARC_NSSErrorHighNSS<= PROC_NSSError;
        elsif(ENT_NSS'event and ENT_NSS = '1')then
            if(ARC_Counter = (ENT_Leangth -1))then
                PROC_NSSError:= ARC_NSSErrorHighNSS;
                ARC_NSSErrorHighNSS<= PROC_NSSError;
            elsif(ARC_CRCStart = true)then
                --spi đã tắt
                PROC_NSSError:= ARC_NSSErrorHighNSS;
                ARC_NSSErrorHighNSS<= PROC_NSSError;
            else
                --lỗi, nss lênh múc cao trong khi đang truyền data
                PROC_NSSError:= '1';--lỗi
                ARC_NSSErrorHighNSS<= PROC_NSSError;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process DeviceEnableHighNSS;
    DeviceEnableLowNSS: process(ENT_NSS, ENT_DeviceResetEvent, ARC_DeviceStatus)is
        variable PROC_NSSError: std_logic:= '0';--lỗi nss
        variable PROC_DeviceStatus: boolean:= false;-- device chua active
    begin
        if(ENT_NSS = '1' or ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1')then
            PROC_DeviceStatus:= false;-- active device
            ARC_DeviceStatus<= PROC_DeviceStatus;
            PROC_NSSError:= '0';
            ARC_NSSErrorLowNSS<= PROC_NSSError;
        elsif(ENT_NSS'event and ENT_NSS = '0')then
            if(ARC_Counter = (ENT_Leangth -1))then
                PROC_DeviceStatus:= true;-- active device
                ARC_DeviceStatus<= PROC_DeviceStatus;
                PROC_NSSError:= ARC_NSSErrorLowNSS;
                ARC_NSSErrorLowNSS<= PROC_NSSError;
            else
                --lỗi, nss giảm xuốn mức 0 trong khi đang truyền data
                PROC_NSSError:= '1';--lỗi
                ARC_NSSErrorLowNSS<= PROC_NSSError;
                PROC_DeviceStatus:= ARC_DeviceStatus;
                ARC_DeviceStatus<= PROC_DeviceStatus;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process DeviceEnableLowNSS;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --Counter
    Counter:process(ENT_ClkIn)is
        variable PROC_I: integer range (ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0:= (ENT_Leangth -1);
        variable PROC_CounterSCKEventReset: std_logic:= '0';--reset tín hiệu ARC_CounterSCKEvent
        variable PROC_DataFrameComputer: boolean:= false; -- chưa ruyền xong một khung data
    begin
        if(ENT_ClkIn'event and ENT_ClkIn = '1')then
            if(ARC_DeviceStatus = true)then
                --Device đã hoặt động và bắt đầu đếm
                if(ARC_CounterSCKEvent = '1')then
                    PROC_CounterSCKEventReset:= '1';--RESERT tin hiệu ARC_CounterSCKEvent
                    ARC_CounterSCKEventReset<= PROC_CounterSCKEventReset;
                    if(PROC_I = 0)then
                        PROC_I:= ENT_Leangth -1;
                        PROC_DataFrameComputer:= true;--đã truyền xong một khung data
                        ARC_DataFrameComputer<= PROC_DataFrameComputer;
                    else
                        PROC_I:= PROC_I -1;
                        PROC_DataFrameComputer:= false;
                        ARC_DataFrameComputer<= PROC_DataFrameComputer;
                    end if;
                    ARC_Counter<= PROC_I;
                else
                    PROC_I:= ARC_Counter;
                    ARC_Counter<= PROC_I;
                    PROC_CounterSCKEventReset:= '0';
                    ARC_CounterSCKEventReset<= PROC_CounterSCKEventReset;
                    PROC_DataFrameComputer:= ARC_DataFrameComputer;
                    ARC_DataFrameComputer<= PROC_DataFrameComputer;
                end if;
            else
                --chưa hoạt động
            end if;
        end if;
    end process Counter;
    CounterEvent: process(ENT_SCK, ARC_CounterSCKEventReset, ARC_DeviceStatus, ENT_DeviceResetEvent)is
    begin
        if(ARC_CounterSCKEventReset = '1' or ARC_DeviceStatus = false or ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1')then
            --reset tín hiệu ARC_CounterSCKEvent
            ARC_CounterSCKEvent<= '0';
        elsif(ENT_SCK'event and ENT_SCK = '0' and ARC_DeviceStatus = true)then
        --giảm giá trị của bộ đếm counter
            ARC_CounterSCKEvent<= '1';
        end if;
    end process CounterEvent;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --DataMosi
    DataMosiControl:process(ENT_SCK, ARC_DataMosiEmptySet ,ARC_DataMosiEmptyReset, ARC_DeviceStatus, ENT_DeviceResetEvent)is
    begin
        if(ARC_DataMosiEmptyReset = '1' OR ARC_DeviceStatus = false or ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1')then
            --reset
            ARC_DataReceiveEvent<= '0';-- sự kiện đọc data từ mosi
        elsif(ARC_DataMosiEmptySet'event and ARC_DataMosiEmptySet = '1')then
            --lấy data
            ARC_DataReceiveEvent<= '1';-- sự kiện đọc data từ mosi
        end if;
    end process DataMosiControl;
    process(ARC_DataMosiEmptySet)is
        variable PROC_DataMosiTemp: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');
    begin
        if(ARC_DataMosiEmptySet'event and ARC_DataMosiEmptySet = '1')then
            PROC_DataMosiTemp:= ARC_DataMosi;
            ARC_DataMosiTemp<= PROC_DataMosiTemp;
        end if;
    end process;
    GetDataMosi: process(ENT_SCK, ARC_DeviceStatus, ENT_NSS, ENT_DeviceResetEvent)is
        variable PROC_DataMosi: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');
    begin
        if(ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1' or ENT_NSS = '1' or ARC_DeviceStatus = false)then
            PROC_DataMosi:= (others=> '0');
            ARC_DataMosi<= PROC_DataMosi;
            ARC_DataMosiEmptySet<= '0';
            ARC_DataMosiEmptyReset<= '0';
        elsif(ENT_SCK'event and ENT_SCK = '1')then
            if(ARC_DeviceStatus = true)then
                PROC_DataMosi(ARC_Counter):= ENT_MOSI;
                ARC_DataMosi<= PROC_DataMosi;
                if(ARC_Counter = 0)then
                    ARC_DataMosiEmptySet<= '1';--set ENT_DataReceiveEvent
                    ARC_DataMosiEmptyReset<= '0';
                else
                    ARC_DataMosiEmptySet<= '0';
                    ARC_DataMosiEmptyReset<= '1';--reset ENT_DataReceiveEvent
                end if;
            else
                ARC_DataMosiEmptyReset<= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process GetDataMosi;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --CRCMiso
    -- CRC_TransmitComputer:process(ARC_DataFrameComputer)is
    -- begin
    --  if(ARC_CRCTransmitComputerReset = '1')then
    --      ARC_CRCTransmitComputer<= false;
    --  elsif(ARC_DataFrameComputer'event and ARC_DataFrameComputer = true)then
    --      if(ARC_DataTransmitEnd = true)then
    --          ARC_CRCTransmitComputer<= true;
    --      else
    --          ARC_CRCTransmitComputer<= false;
    --      end if;
    --  end if;
    -- end process;
    -- CRC_TransmitStart: process(ARC_CRCDataInputCompute, ARC_CRCTransmitStartReset)is
    -- begin
    --  if(ARC_CRCTransmitStartReset = '1')then
    --      ARC_CRCTransmitStart<= false;--không cho phép truyền crc
    --  elsif(ARC_CRCDataInputCompute'event and ARC_CRCDataInputCompute = '1')then
    --      ARC_CRCTransmitStart<= true;--cho phép truyền crc
    --  end if;
    -- end process CRC_TransmitStart;
    CRC_Event: process(ENT_CRCEvent, ARC_DeviceStatus, ENT_DeviceResetEvent)is
    begin
        if(ARC_DeviceStatus = false or ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1')then
            ARC_CRCEvent<= '0';
        elsif(ENT_CRCEvent'event and ENT_CRCEvent = '1')then
            ARC_CRCEvent<= '1';--đả có tín hiệu truyền crc
        end if;
    end process CRC_Event;
    CRC_DataNewEvent: process(ARC_CRCDataNewEvent, ARC_CRCDataNewEventReset, ENT_DeviceResetEvent)is

    begin
        if(ARC_CRCDataNewEventReset = '1' or ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1')then
            --reset
            ARC_CRCDataNewEventFlag<= '0';
        elsif(ARC_CRCDataNewEvent'event and ARC_CRCDataNewEvent = '0')then
            --khi có data mớ trong datamiso
            ARC_CRCDataNewEventFlag<= '1';--cờ cho biết có data mới trong DataMiso
        end if;
    end process;
    CRC_DataInput: process(ARC_CRCCLK)is
        variable PROC_DataOne: boolean:= true;-- data đầu tiên
        variable PROC_CRCDataInput: std_logic_vector(((ENT_Leangth *2) -1) downto 0):= (others=> '0');
        variable PROC_DataCRC: std_logic_vector(ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0):= (others=> '0');--data CRC
    begin
        if(ARC_CRCCLK'event and ARC_CRCCLK = '1')then
            if(ARC_CRCDataNewEventFlag = '1')then
                ARC_CRCDataNewEventReset<= '1';--reset
                PROC_CRCDataInput:= ARC_CRCDataInput;
                PROC_CRCDataInput:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataInput) sll ENT_Leangth);
                PROC_CRCDataInput((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):= ARC_DataMiso;
                if(PROC_DataOne = true)then
                    -- data là đầu tiên, không chạy crc
                    if(ARC_CRCEvent = '1')then
                        --chỉ truyề 1 data, hoàng thành crc
                        PROC_CRCDataInput:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataInput) sll ENT_Leangth);
                        CRC_EndOneData:for i in ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0 loop
                            if(PROC_CRCDataInput((ENT_Leangth *2) -1) = '0')then
                                --bit đầu tiên là '0'
                                PROC_CRCDataInput:= PROC_CRCDataInput xor ARC_CRCZeroVector;
                            else
                                PROC_CRCDataInput:= PROC_CRCDataInput xor ARC_CRCPolynomial;
                            end if;
                            PROC_CRCDataInput:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataInput) sll 1);--dịch sang trái
                        end loop CRC_EndOneData;
                        PROC_DataCRC:= PROC_CRCDataInput((ENT_Leangth *2) -1 downto ENT_Leangth);
                        ARC_CRCDataInput<= PROC_CRCDataInput;
                        ARC_CRCDataOutput<= PROC_DataCRC;
                        PROC_DataOne:= true;
                        ARC_CRCDataOne<= PROC_DataOne;
                    else
                        ARC_CRCDataInput<= PROC_CRCDataInput;
                        PROC_DataOne:= false;
                        ARC_CRCDataOne<= PROC_DataOne;
                        PROC_DataCRC:= ARC_CRCDataOutput;
                        ARC_CRCDataOutput<= PROC_DataCRC;
                    end if;
                else
                    --chạy crc
                    CRC:for i in ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0 loop
                        if(PROC_CRCDataInput((ENT_Leangth *2) -1) = '0')then
                            --bit đầu tiên là '0'
                            PROC_CRCDataInput:= PROC_CRCDataInput xor ARC_CRCZeroVector;
                        else
                            PROC_CRCDataInput:= PROC_CRCDataInput xor ARC_CRCPolynomial;
                        end if;
                        PROC_CRCDataInput:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataInput) sll 1);--dịch sang trái
                        ARC_CRCDataInput<= PROC_CRCDataInput;
                    end loop CRC;
                    if(ARC_CRCDataInputCompute = '1')then
                        --đã nhận hết data miso
                        CRC_End:for i in ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0 loop
                            if(PROC_CRCDataInput((ENT_Leangth *2) -1) = '0')then
                                --bit đầu tiên là '0'
                                PROC_CRCDataInput:= PROC_CRCDataInput xor ARC_CRCZeroVector;
                            else
                                PROC_CRCDataInput:= PROC_CRCDataInput xor ARC_CRCPolynomial;
                            end if;
                            PROC_CRCDataInput:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataInput) sll 1);--dịch sang trái
                        end loop CRC_End;
                        PROC_DataCRC:= PROC_CRCDataInput((ENT_Leangth *2) -1 downto ENT_Leangth);--lấy data CRC khi hoàng thành
                        ARC_CRCDataInput<= PROC_CRCDataInput;
                        ARC_CRCDataOutput<= PROC_DataCRC;
                        PROC_DataOne:= true;
                        ARC_CRCDataOne<= PROC_DataOne;
                    else
                        ARC_CRCDataInput<= PROC_CRCDataInput;
                        PROC_DataOne:= false;
                        ARC_CRCDataOne<= PROC_DataOne;
                        PROC_DataCRC:= ARC_CRCDataOutput;
                        ARC_CRCDataOutput<= PROC_DataCRC;
                    end if;
                end if;
            else
                ARC_CRCDataNewEventReset<= '0';
                PROC_DataCRC:= ARC_CRCDataOutput;
                ARC_CRCDataOutput<= PROC_DataCRC;
                PROC_CRCDataInput:= ARC_CRCDataInput;
                ARC_CRCDataInput<= PROC_CRCDataInput;
                PROC_DataOne:= ARC_CRCDataOne;
                ARC_CRCDataOne<= PROC_DataOne;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process CRC_DataInput;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --CRCMosi
    DataInputCRC:process(ARC_CRCDataMosiInputNewEvent, ARC_DeviceStatus, ENT_DeviceResetEvent)is
        variable PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth *2) -1 downto 0):= (others=> '0');
        variable PROC_CRCOneData: std_logic:= '1';-- chỉ nhận 1 data
        variable PROC_CRCDataComputer: std_logic_vector((ENT_Leangth -1) downto 0):=(others=> '0');--data crc đã hòang thành
    begin
        if(ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1' or ARC_DeviceStatus = false)then
            --reset
            PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= (others=> '0');
            PROC_CRCDataComputer:= (others=> '0');
            ARC_CRCDataMosiTemp<= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp;
            ARC_CRCDataMosiComputer<= PROC_CRCDataComputer;--Data khi tính toáng xong crc
            PROC_CRCOneData:= '1';
        elsif(ARC_CRCDataMosiInputNewEvent'event and ARC_CRCDataMosiInputNewEvent = '1' and ENT_CRCEnable = true)then
                if(PROC_CRCOneData = '1')then
                    --mới nhận được 1 data
                    if(ARC_CRCDataMosiReceiveComputer = true)then
                        --đã nhận hết data
                        PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp(ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0):= ARC_DataMosiTemp;
                        PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp) sll ENT_Leangth);
                        CRCMOSIComputerOneData: for i in ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0 loop
                            if(PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp((ENT_Leangth *2) -1) = '0')then
                                PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp xor ARC_CRCZeroVector;
                            else
                                PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp xor ARC_CRCPolynomial;
                            end if;
                            PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp) sll 1);
                        end loop CRCMOSIComputerOneData;
                        PROC_CRCDataComputer:= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp((ENT_Leangth *2) -1 downto ENT_Leangth);--Data khi tính toáng xong crc
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiTemp<= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp;
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiComputer<= PROC_CRCDataComputer;--Data khi tính toáng xong crc
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiComputerEvent<= '1';--đã hoàng thành tính CRC
                    else
                        --chưa nhận hết data
                        PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp) sll ENT_Leangth);
                        PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp(ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0):= ARC_DataMosiTemp;
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiTemp<= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp;
                        PROC_CRCDataComputer:= ARC_CRCDataMosiComputer;--Data khi tính toáng xong crc
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiComputer<= PROC_CRCDataComputer;--Data khi tính toáng xong crc
                    end if;
                    PROC_CRCOneData:= '0';
                else
                    PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp) sll ENT_Leangth);
                    PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp(ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0):= ARC_DataMosiTemp;
                    PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= (ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0 => '0')&ARC_DataMosiTemp;
                    CRCMOSI: for i in ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0 loop
                        if(PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp((ENT_Leangth *2) -1) = '0')then
                            PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp xor ARC_CRCZeroVector;
                        else
                            PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp xor ARC_CRCPolynomial;
                        end if;
                        PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp) sll 1);
                    end loop CRCMOSI;
                    if(ARC_CRCDataMosiReceiveComputer = true)then
                        --đã nhận hết data
                        CRCMOSIComputer: for i in ENT_Leangth -1 downto 0 loop
                            if(PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp((ENT_Leangth *2) -1) = '0')then
                                PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp xor ARC_CRCZeroVector;
                            else
                                PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp xor ARC_CRCPolynomial;
                            end if;
                            PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp) sll 1);
                        end loop CRCMOSIComputer;
                        PROC_CRCDataComputer:= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp((ENT_Leangth *2) -1 downto ENT_Leangth);--Data khi tính toáng xong crc
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiComputer<= PROC_CRCDataComputer;--Data khi tính toáng xong crc
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiTemp<= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp;
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiComputerEvent<= '1';--đã hoàng thành tính CRC
                    else
                        --chưa nhận hết data
                        PROC_CRCDataComputer:= ARC_CRCDataMosiComputer;--Data khi tính toáng xong crc
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiComputer<= PROC_CRCDataComputer;--Data khi tính toáng xong crc
                        PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp:= ARC_CRCDataMosiTemp;
                        ARC_CRCDataMosiTemp<= PROC_CRCDataMosiTemp;
                    end if;
                    PROC_CRCOneData:= '0';
                end if;
        end if;
    end process DataInputCRC;
    CRCMosiCheckAccess: process (ENT_ClkIn, ENT_DeviceResetEvent, ARC_DeviceStatus, ARC_Counter, ARC_CRCDataMosiComputerEvent)is
    begin
        if(ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1' or ARC_DeviceStatus = false)then
            ARC_CRCDataMosiCheckAccess<= false;
        elsif(ENT_ClkIn'event and ENT_ClkIn = '1' and ARC_DeviceStatus = true and ARC_Counter = 1 and ARC_CRCDataMosiComputerEvent = '1')then
            ARC_CRCDataMosiCheckAccess<= true;--CHO HÉP KIỂM TRA CRC
        end if;
    end process CRCMosiCheckAccess;
    CRCMosiCheck:process(ARC_CRCDataMosiCheckEvent, ENT_DeviceResetEvent, ARC_DeviceStatus, ARC_CRCDataMosiCheckAccess)is--kiểm tra crc nhận có trùng với crc đã tính hay không
    begin
        if(ENT_DeviceResetEvent = '1' or ARC_DeviceStatus = false)then
            ARC_CRCCheckError<= '0';--crc giống
        elsif(ARC_CRCDataMosiCheckEvent'event and ARC_CRCDataMosiCheckEvent = '1' and ARC_CRCDataMosiCheckAccess = true)then
            if(ARC_DataMosi = ARC_CRCDataMosiComputer)then
                ARC_CRCCheckError<= '0';--crc giống
            else
                ARC_CRCCheckError<= '1';--crc khác, lỗi
            end if;
        end if;
    end process CRCMosiCheck;
end architecture SPI_Slave_Behavioral;
```

how to get rid of this warning"WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <DataInputCRC.PROC_CRCOneData> of sequential type is unconnected in block <SPI_Slave>."

Answer (score -1):

I run simulation and synthesis of this code on Vivado and here are my comments:

1. As a simulation run, it runs ok (no errors, no warnings).
2. As a synthesis run, there is an error on line 112:

   elsif(ENT_DataNewEvent'event and ENT_DataNewEvent = '1')then

Look like you are using 'event, which can only be used in a simulation run. So this code can be simulated but not implemented in a chip.
Basically looks like the code you are sharing is a simulations IP and not a design IP.
If you want more answers, I recommend you to add more information to the questions, like: a) Software you are using, b) FPGA you are targeting c) What Run are you executing (sim, sinthesis, implementation, bitstream?).